# How to represent hierarchical structure in IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, indexeddb, hierarchical

I have a complex and variable hierarchical data structure that I will be storing locally from JavaScript. Based on my research thus far it looks like IndexedDB is my best choice for a solution.

My structure is composed of similar elements, each of which has a unique identifier and an arbitrary number of children elements. There can be any number of root elements. Elements can be symbolic links to other existing elements. I plan to make an objectStore keyed on the ID, from there I have considered a few options:

1) I can insert the root elements directly. This makes hierarchical operations (prune, clone, graft) and backups to a server much easier- trivial really; but also makes searching for deeper elements very expensive more complex to implement.

2) I can insert each element directly into the store and use the children element IDs to rebuild the hierarchy as needed. This speeds searching up to O(log n) but recreates all of the hierarchical difficulties of a relational DB.

If there is a way to:
 a) create an index or query that quickly iterates through the entire data structure in IndexeDB 
or b) create multiple references to an object in IndexedDB

it simplifies the problem greatly, other than that I'm not sure how best to approach this one.

Comment: I know this more than three years ago, but did you find a solution? I'm looking for a way to store and search HTML client-side.

Answer (score -1):

Creating indexes in IndexedDB:

```
        var oOptions = { keyPath : "id", autoIncrement : true };
        var oStore = dbHandle.createObjectStore( "yourstore", oOptions );
        var oIxOptions = { unique: true, multientry: false };            
        oStore.createIndex( "IxYourIndexName", "id", oIxOptions );
```

Querying the object store using the id and opening a cursor on it for iteration:

```
        var transaction = dbHandle.transaction(["yourstore"],"readwrite");   
        var os = transaction.objectStore("yourstore");
        var cursorRequest  = null;   
        var ix = os.index("IxYourIndexName");   
        var keyRange = IDBKeyRange.only(1);// get by id = 1 
        cursorRequest = ix.openCursor(keyRange);     
        cursorRequest.onsuccess = function (ev){
           var cursor = ev.target.result;                  
        };               
        cursorRequest.onerror = function (ev) {
          console.log("  Error: " + ev.message);         
       };
```